# Not seeing the Git functions in my toolbar in Pycharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm, toolbar

The problem is that after I installed Git and also went to VCS --> Enable Version Control Integration --> Git, I cannot see the functions in the toolbar...

It should look like this: [Git working in toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Q8U.png)

But mine is looking like this: [Not seein Git functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlOCI.png)

I also tried to add the functions threw the settings, but then it just looks like this and I don't want it that way: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKulF.png)

My current versions are:

Pycharm 2023.2.1 Community Edition
Git 2.44.0

Thanks for reading. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the new UI, the first image is from the old UI which you can revert to by pressing CTRL + ',' and unticking 'Enable new UI'.